# Why when I press button "run" in python it does not give any output?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I have started a python course few days ago. I am having problems with my loop in the python assignment which is:

Given a set of N measurements, (r1, r2, . . . , rN ), we will initially assign the odd-numbered measurements to
class 1 and the even numbered measurements to class 2. Then the following two steps are repeated:

• Update step: Compute the mean value (average) of the measurements within each cluster.

• Assignment step: Assign each measurement to the cluster with the closest mean value. In case of a tie,
assign the measurement to cluster 1.

Repeat the above steps until the cluster assignments do not change. It can not be determined in advance how 
many steps will be needed before the clustering assignment stabilizes.

Problem definition
Create a function that takes as an input a vector of reflectance measurements and returns a vector of cluster
assignments computed using the algorithm described above.

I have created a code:

```
import numpy as np
import math
def clusterAnalysis(reflectance):
    ref=np.size(reflectance)# all N measurements
    even=np.any(ref %2==0)# N measurements are even numbers
    uneven=np.any(ref%2>0)# N measurements are odd number
    mean1=np.mean(even)#average of even numbers in cluster 2
    mean2=np.mean(uneven)# average of odd numbers in cluster 1
    sub1=abs(ref-mean1)
    sub2=abs(ref-mean2)
    while sub1<=sub2:
        clusterAssigment="1"
    else:
        clusterAssigment="2"
    return clusterAssigments
#print(clusterAnalysis(np.array([1.7, 1.6, 1.3, 1.3, 2.8, 1.4,
#2.8, 2.6, 1.6, 2.7])))
```

**New code:

````
import math
def clusterAnalysis(reflectance):
    reflectance=np.arange(reflectance.size)
    evens =reflectance % 2 == 0 # N measurements are even numbers
    clusters = np.ones(reflectance.shape)
    clusters[evens] = 2
    while True:
        mean_even=np.mean(reflectance[evens])
        mean_odd=np.mean(reflectance[np.logical_not(evens)])
        diff_even = np.abs(reflectance - mean_even) 
        diff_odd = np.abs(reflectance - mean_odd)
        new_clusters= np.ones(reflectance.shape)
        new_clusters[diff_even < diff_odd] = 2
        clusterAssigments= new_clusters

        if np.all(clusters == new_clusters):
            break
        clusters = new_clusters
        clusterAssigments= new_clusters
    return clusterAssigments 
print(clusterAnalysis(np.array([1.7, 1.6, 1.3, 1.3, 2.8, 1.4,2.8, 2.6, 1.6, 2.7])))```**



The code above does not work at all. My output should be :`2 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 `
I have been working on this for last 2 days and I just dont know what I am doing wrong...
````

Comment: why do you use `while` instead of `if` ?

Comment: don't you get error message when you run it? I see variable `clusterAssigments` with `s` which you didn't defined - you have on `clusterAssigment` without `s`

Comment: maybe use `print()` in different palces of code to see values in variables and to shee which part of code is executed - or learn how to use debugger.

Comment: I am using ```while``` because I dont know how many iterations it takes before the clusterAssignments are unchanged according to the assignment

Comment: I just fixed ```clusterAssigment``` to ```clusterAssigments``` thanks for the comment furas, but it still does not run...

Comment: if you don't change values inside `while` then it will never end. And `else` with `while` works different then `if/else` - `else` is executed only if you use `break` inside `while`

Comment: ok, but now im thinking how to change ```sub1``` and ```sub2``` inside the loop...

Comment: i don't understand what you calcualate but you can change sub1, sub2 inside `while` the same way as change outside `while` - `sub1 = ...` , `sub2 = ...`. But I said before: use `print()` to see what you have in variable - it helsp a lot.

Comment: BTW: if you want many values on exit then you should create empty list at start and `append()` values to list and later `return` this list.

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop never ends. You never modify `sub1` or `sub2`, so the while loop just spins and spins and `sub1` is always less than `sub2`.

The problem you've got is that at each iteration of the while loop, you to work out the new clusters, based on the mean from the old clusters, then check if they've changed.

You're right that you need a while loop, you can use something like this:

```
def clusterAnalysis(reflectance):
    # Work out your odd/even clusters to start it off
    # EDIT: I misread how this bit works - see the update.
    # You don't want to use the size here:
    #     you want to use a list of numbers the size
    # of reflectance [0, 1, 2, ..., n]
    even_numbers = np.arange(reflectance.size) % 2 == 0

    # Now we'll create an array to hold the cluster ids, that's the
    # same shape as reflectance.
    # By default it'll store ones. Then we'll change all the entries
    # for even numbers to hold twos
    clusters = np.ones(reflectance.shape)

    # This uses what's called "logical indexing" - it'll change all the elements
    # that equal "true" in even_numbers
    clusters[even_numbers] = 2

    # This will create a never-ending while loop, but we'll manually
    # end it using 'break'
    while True:
        # Work out the new clusters, by working out the means of the two 
        # clusters and finding the closest to the reflectance numbers
        # Clue: You can use logical indexing here like we did above
        cluster_1_mean = ...
        cluster_2_mean = ...
        new_clusters = ...

        # This is the really important bit - we've created the new array 
        # `new_clusters` above and we want to check if it's the same as 
        # the last one. If it is, we'll use `break` which tells python
        # to stop doing the loop now.
        if np.all(clusters == new_clusters):
            break

        # We'll only reach here if we haven't called 'break' - so we'll update with the new clusters and we can go again
        clusters = new_clusters

    # Once the while loop is finished, we should return the clusters array.
    return clusters
```

**EDIT:**
I'll try to give you the pieces of the puzzle for the clustering bit.

Lets say I have two list of 20 random numbers between 0 and 200, and I want to get the mean of the odd and even values:

```
x = np.random.randint(200, size=(20))

# Just like above, we'll get the id of each element in an array [0, 1, ..., 20]
x_ids = np.arange(x.size)
evens = x_ids % 2 == 0

# We'll get the mean of all the even `x`'s
mean_even = np.mean(x[evens])

# And we can do it the other way round for the odds
mean_odd = np.mean(x[np.logical_not(evens)])
```

**Another edit:**

OK, last puzzle piece :)

So we want to find which of `x` is closest to `mean_even` and which is closest to `mean_odd`. We can do something similar to your original attempt:

```
diff_even = np.abs(x - mean_even) 
diff_odd = np.abs(x - mean_odd)

# Start by creating a new clusters array, just like we did before,
# where all the ids are originally set to `1`.    
new_clusters = np.ones(x.shape)

# Now get the numbers closest to `diff_even` and set their cluster to
# two.
# Because we're using less-than, it means that any that are equally
# close to both means will stay in cluster one. If we wanted it to
#  work so they went to cluster 2 by default, we could use `<=`.
new_clusters[diff_even < diff_odd] = 2
```

You'll need to change some variable names around to use logical indexing to get the means from the clusters array instead of the evens array, but this should give you basically everything you need.

*Note that I made a mistake earlier when I did the `mean_odd`. I broke the logical indexing by accidentally turning the boolean array into numbers, which is why I've updated it to use `np.logical_not`. I can explain how that works in more detail if of interest.*

Comment: I need the ```while``` because I dont know how many iterations are needed... But how do I modify ```sub1``` and ```sub2```?

Comment: Yes, but you need to update sub1 and sub2 inside the loop. I'm updating my answer after thinking through the problem a bit more deeply.

Comment: Actually, there's a lot wrong here, and I don't want to spoiler the whole task for you. I'll try to explain in words on the answer.

Comment: Any help will be great, I am so confused right now.. I have rewritten this code many times and it seems that I have a problem with understanding this assignment...

Comment: See my edit. I'm happy to answer more questions. I don't want to take away from your learning by giving too much away in one go though :)

Comment: I am still struggling with understanding what to put in while loop, under: while True:
        ```# Work out the new clusters, just like you did above
        new_clusters = ...```

Comment: Can you help to understand what to put in ```new_clusters``` after I updated this: ```while True:
        cluster_1_mean=np.mean(even_numbers)
        cluster_2_mean=np.mean(odd_numbers)
        new_clusters = ...```

Comment: I think that should be everything. It'll need stringing together and you'll want to make sure you use the right arrays and that you get your comparisons the right way round, but everything you need to solve the problem is there now - I've just implemented it fully and tested it and it works :)

Comment: last puzzle piece you wrote is that all supposed to be under ```while```?  I implemented what you wrote and I get a result ```2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.```....

Comment: Yup. It needs to be in the while so everything gets updated.

Comment: I have pasted the code into the post pasge with title "New code"..Can you take a look and point me to the mistake?

Comment: Close. You want to use `clusters == 1` and `clusters == 2` for your indexing in the loop, not `evens`. Think about which arrays get updated and which ones don't. Also, you can just return `clusters` - there's no need to create a new variable.

Comment: I have to ```return clusterAssignments``` because I need to submit this assigment in a certain template form...but now I replaced ```evens``` with ```clusters == 1``` and ```clusters == 2``` and i get an error : RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
  new_clusters[diff_even < diff_odd] = 2

Comment: I changed ```new_clusters= np.ones(reflectance.shape)``` to ```new_clusters= clusters``` inside the loop and it gives me a result now but a wrong one ```[2. 1. 2. 1. 2. 1. 2. 1. 2. 1.]``` and it should be ```2 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 2 1```..do you know why?

Comment: I am looking forward to hearing from you  n00dle tomorrow:) Im really close of solving this assignment fully and it is all thanks to you.

Comment: n00dle can you help please?

Comment: Sorry I'm at work. Put some print statements in, look at what's in the variables and work out why it's not showing what you expect to see.

Comment: of course, I understand. I am sorry for taking your time anyways. It seems that in the code it does not work for three variables on the list:```2.8 1.4 2.8``` My code gives ```212``` and it should be ```121```

Comment: I still cant figure it out n00dle. I really want to understand this and it turns out that I dont have to submit this since it is an optional assigment but I was wondering(if its not too much to ask). Would you have time to skype in the evening so we could walk through this assigment? I understand if you say no but I would really appreciate if you could.

Comment: So your print shows you that the clusters are getting labelled the wrong way round, look at what it is that defines the labels and try reversing the logic. I don't have time to Skype I'm afraid. Ignore the code and work through in your head how exactly the algorithm should work to solve your problem. Use a pen and paper or a whiteboard. Then look at the code you have there and see how they match up.